# Checking if an int after division is a whole number in an if statement

Tags: c, math, if-statement, int

I'm trying to write a short program, and I need to (using an if statement) check if something is a whole number.

Basically,

```
if(number / 3 = whole) {
   lorem ipsum
}
else if (number / 5 = whole) { 
   lorem ipsum 
}
```

Imaginary pseudo/hybrid code ftw.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The operator Piotr S. used above is called the modulus operator. You should google and check it out!

Comment: if (number % 3 == 0){blah}elseif(number % 5 == 0){blah}?

Comment: And thanks Steppel for editing and adding [code] tags.

Comment: @Scott Note: C calls `%` the remainder operator: "the result of the % operator is the remainder" C11dr §6.5.5 5.  Similar to modulus, but differences with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (number % 3 == 0) { /*lorem ipsum*/ }    
else if (number % 5 == 0) { /*lorem ipsum*/ }
```

Comment: Trying to do that, says to wait three seconds... There ya go!